# How can I echo this PHP variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this PHP variable:

```
<?php

$share_url = $site_url . '/' . $lang . '/app/' . $application_url . '/' . $result_id . '/' . urlencode($f_name) . '/' . $foldername . '/?utm_source=' . $tracking . '&utm_medium=' . $tracking . '&utm_campaign=' . $tracking;

?>
```

I want to echo it in this JavaScript code instead of "I WANT TO ECHO IT HERE":

```
FB.login(
            function(response){
                if (response.authResponse)
                {
                    app_is_ready = false;
                    custom_start_button('loading');
                    generateresult(appname);
                    console.log("# app authorized");
                    console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                            var opts = {
                            link: 'I WANT TO ECHO IT HERE',
                            };
                            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
                            {
                            if (!response || response.error)
                            {
                            console.log(response.error);
                            alert('Posting error occured');
                            }else{
                            //alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                            }
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please login with Facebook to see your result!");
                    console.log("# app not authorized");
                }
            }, scopes
        )

        ;
```

I looked at other questions but they don't answer my questions.

Comment: What questions did you look at and why were they not relevant to your question?

Comment: It seems like a variable assignment question. Try to use a console.log() in a function by itself

Answer (score 1):

```
link: <?php echo $php_var; ?>
```

you can have an inline php block and echo the variable in there

Comment: I tried it the code you've written, it doesn't work for me I don't know the reason... Please, what did you meant by an inline php block?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways, although, I'd not recommend the first.

**First**

You could use PHP to create a global variable, and then access that on load. You'd do this in your HTML.

Something like

````
```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var link = <?php echo $share_url; ?>
    </script>
```
````

Then you could access this from your JS file. Although, it's messy, mixes PHP and JS.

**Second:**

Create an endpoint that returns the URL to the JS file, which would request the URL. It's cleaner and doesn't require mixing JS and PHP.

Comment: If you could please inform me more about the second method?

Comment: You'd create a URL that would respond with your link. For example: `domain.com/share-url` would return a link as it's response body. 

In your JS, you'd do a simple AJAX request to your endpoint and you should be returned with some the link. Then you can use that in your other JS code.

Although, if you only wanted the user logged in user to see this data, you'd have to think about auth. Although, it would be in your JS anyway.